# leave a for each loop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I want to leave the for each loop as soon as the boolean is set to true.

```
for each (xmlEvent in arEvents)
{
    var xmlEvent:XMLList = XMLList(event);
    if(xmlEvent.id == artistEvent.id)
    {
        boolExists = true;
    }
}
```

I've tried break and such, but this all doesn't work.

Comment: break should work, are you 'breaking' before `boolExists = true` or after? It should come after you set the variable.

Comment: Could you update the question with the "updated" code that includes your break statement?  That way we can see what could cause the break statement to not be evaluated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [break](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#break) operator

```
for each (xmlEvent in arEvents)
{
    var xmlEvent:XMLList = XMLList(event);
    if(xmlEvent.id == artistEvent.id)
    {
        boolExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [some()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#some%28%29) method?  It'll handle all that for you.

```
boolExists = arEvents.some(
  function (xmlEvent:*, index:int, arr:Array):Boolean {
    return xmlEvent.id == artistEvent.id;
  });
```

*Note: The anonymous function is used only for brevity.*

---

For clarity, the `some()` method only iterates over the array *until* the first item that returns true is reached, at which point iteration is terminated and the result (true) is returned.